# How to generate a fake bash history file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I need to develop a demonstration machine and, for various reasons, I would need to have a lengthy `.bash_history` file, but I do not want to use my own for obvious privacy reasons.

Is there are way/place where I can generate/get a random file with random (but reasonable) commands?

**EDIT**: to clarify, the commands to not need to follow any particular logic or "story", they just need to make sense if someone has to briefly have a look at `.bash_history`. The purpose of this is that a bunch of real commands (that I will provide) must be hidden inside a longer and useless list of commands

Comment: BTW: Do you need reasonable just as in it looks like something a user could of typed into the shell, or does it actually need to match up with the machine? E.g., would be a problem if it included a bunch of commands that aren't installed on the machine, or files and directories that don't exist? Or even more strictly, does it need to make sense to someone reading it? (E.g., does it need to make sense that "yeah, the user cd'd to the source directory, worked on code for a while, cd'd elsewhere..." vs. random commands with no "story"?)

Comment: Oh no, it can be completely unrelated to the machine. Just a bunch of random commands that make sense and when someone reads it, it would be "oh yeah he did that, wathever". I've edited the question to make it clearer, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the issue before, as I needed fake machines for a ctf.
My general way is to look for "bash history pastebin" on my favorite search engine.

This leads to these for example:

- https://pastebin.com/bvyhfTcj
- https://pastebin.com/cjfPrYxt
- https://pastebin.com/6JhY1bru

Good luck!

Comment: Of course! How could I forget pastebin :D Thanks, mate